# Labeling streets built from GPS records

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, labeling, streets, address

Suppose we are getting a street map built from GPS records. That map would only have initially street segments (just the way Waze started), with no street names nor numbers (addresses).

What would you recommend for getting the names for those streets?

Would it be correct to grab data from OpenStreetMap or Google Maps perhaps?

Or that would violate some kind of licensing?

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

This seems illegal in common and strictly dependent to the which part of the google maps you'll use. Because different countries have different rules on this also google has local suppliers which can follow you. Google and other map suppliers putting traps in their data for preventing and determining this kind of works.

I suggest you to find a local info from a governmental office, municipality or some other data supplier.